# Combining and improving 2 ahk scripts into 1

Tags: script, autohotkey, gaming, combine, simplification

I've created a script by editing from those scripts I found around about gaming. I'm not even sure if it's 100% effective, but somehow I kind of know what I want.

Is it possible to combine the below 2 scripts into 1 so I don't have to run both scripts simultaneously? If there's any better way to write it down it would really be appreciated. Then I can use it as a guidance and edit.

The below script's loop is supposed to run when I hold the xbutton1.

```
^s:: suspend
;Script
~$*xbutton1::
Loop           
{
    GetKeyState, var, xbutton1, P
    If var = U
        Break
Send 9
Sleep 10
Send, {0 down}
Sleep 1600
Send, {0 up}
}
```

The below second script kind of works the same. When I hold the numpad3, it should send a keystroke and immediately push and hold the next one for 2.5 seconds.

```
^s:: suspend
;Script
~$*Numpad3::
Loop           
{
    GetKeyState, var, Numpad3, P
    If var = U
        Break
Send e
Sleep 10
Send, {9 down}
Sleep 2500
Send, {9 up}
}
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone combined and simplified it or made it more effective.

Answer (score 1):

umm scripts lines should have been one under another.

First script

```
^s:: suspend
;Script
~$*xbutton1::
Loop
{
    GetKeyState, var, xbutton1, P
    If var = U
        Break
Send 9
Sleep 10
Send, {0 down}
Sleep 1600
Send, {0 up}
}
```

Second script

```
^s:: suspend
;Script
~$*xbutton1::
Loop
{
    GetKeyState, var, xbutton1, P
    If var = U
        Break
Send 9
Sleep 10
Send, {0 down}
Sleep 1600
Send, {0 up}
}
```